# Drag and Drop Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, getelementbyid

In my project I've got a bunch of images, and each image does different functions, the thing is that I want to know what is the image that the user has dragged, and then make a function or other.

Here's my code :

```
Javascript (Drag and Drop)
    <script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {

    ev.dataTransfer.setData(ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData();
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    if data == gr {
        loadFiles2();
    }

}
</script>
```

My html :

```
<li>
    <a href='#'>
       <span>
          <img src="images/metals/AR.png" id="ar" class='metales' ondragstart="drag(event)"></img>
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="images/metals/GR.png" id="gr" class='metales' ondragstart="drag(event)"></img>
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="images/metals/GW.png" id="gw" class='metales' ondragstart="drag(event)"></img>
       </span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target` property, it will point to current image object:

```
function drop(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but there's any way to compare the drag image? Ex : if getElementById(ar){function1()}if getElemenById(gr){function2()}, etc... It's an example...

Comment: Sure. Say you have reference `var ar = document.getElementById("ar")`. Than you can do `if (ev.target === ar) {...}`.